# primefaces single selection datatable pagination + rowIndexVar

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have a datatable with columns containing images.

```
<p:dataTable id="tabexam"
             lazy="true"
             paginatorPosition="bottom"
             var="exam"
             value="#{dyna.lazyModel}"
             widgetVar="examTable"
             emptyMessage="No results"
             paginator="true"
             rows="#{dyna.rows}" 
             selection="#{dyna.selectedExamen}"
             rowKey="#{exam.studyUid}"
             selectionMode="single"
             rowIndexVar="rowx"
             resizableColumns="false"  
             draggableColumns="true"
             paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"  >
```

On simple text columns when you select a row it gets selected and highlighted correctly.

The problem is with columns that contain p:graphicimage:

```
<p:column headerText="#{column.userListname}"
          sortBy="#{column.dbname}"
          filterBy="#{column.dbname}"
          filterMatchMode="exact" 
          style="#{column.visible==true? 'text-align:center!important;vertical-align: middle!important;':'display:none!important;'}"
          width="#{column.visible==true? 16:0}"
          resizable="#{column.visible==true? column.resizable:false}" 
          rendered="#{column.dbname == 'studyPatientState'}">

           <p:graphicImage value="/images/study_State_icons/#{exam.studyPatientState}.png" styleClass="imagero"
                          onclick="examTable.unselectAllRows();
                                        examTable.selectRow(#{rowx});"/>
</p:column>
```

As you see in order to highlight rows on graphicImage click, i had to add this js:

```
onclick="examTable.unselectAllRows();examTable.selectRow(#{rowx});"
```

The problem is when i switch to another page those js functions cease to work.

I have noticed that in order this to work i need to reset the rowIndexVar for every page, but how may implement such thing.

what am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

There is one more alternative here using JQuery, try this.

`onclick="clickParent(this)"`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   function clickParent(imgElement){
     var tdElement = $(imgElement).parents("td");
     $(tdElement).click()
   }
</script>
```

The above approach will send the Image element to the fuinction, the function will seach through the Parents until it reaches the TD element and Invokes the `click` event on the `td`.